# How to write a test for custom JUnit assertion?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, assertion

Let's say I created my own `assertSomething(...)` method. How can I write a unit test to verify that it is correctly failing the test case using it?

Comment: helpful info : https://www.guru99.com/junit-assert.html

Comment: Nothing saying you can't write a unit test for it just as you would anything else. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this page is not helpful for my specific question. I am creating my own JUnit assertion and I'd like to unit test its code. So I need to have test cases to check if:
- test case passes when my assertion allows it
- test case fails when my assertion disallows it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly I see the next way:

```
@Test
public void assertSomethingSuccessTest() {
    // given
    final Object givenActualResult = new Object(); // put your objects here
    final Object givenExpectedResult = new Object(); // put your objects here

    // when
    assertSomething(givenActualResult, givenExpectedResult);

    // then
    // no exception is expected here
}

// TODO: specify exactly your exception here if any
@Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
public void assertSomethingFailedTest() {
    // given
    final Object givenActualResult = new Object(); // put your objects here
    final Object givenExpectedResult = new Object(); // put your objects here

    // when
    assertSomething(givenActualResult, givenExpectedResult);

    // then
    // an exception is expected here, see annotated expected exception.
}
```

If you need to verify an exception as well:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void assertSomethingFailedTest() {
    // given
    final Object givenActualResult = new Object(); // put your objects here
    final Object givenExpectedResult = new Object(); // put your objects here

    // and
    thrown.expect(RuntimeException.class);
    thrown.expectMessage("happened?");

    // when
    assertSomething(givenActualResult, givenExpectedResult);

    // then
    // an exception is expected here, see configured ExpectedException rule.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Rules, that were introduced in Junit 4.7. Especially TestWatcher.

TestWatcher is a base class for Rules that take note of the testing action, without modifying it. For example, this class will keep a log of each passing and failing test:

```
public static class WatchmanTest {
  private static String watchedLog;

  @Rule
  public TestWatcher watchman= new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
      watchedLog+= description + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
      watchedLog+= description + " " + "success!\n";
     }
  };

  @Test
  public void fails() {
    fail();
  }

  @Test
  public void succeeds() {
  }
}
```